# rails app : same instruction, one use scope, other not, but not same result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I have a scope like this:

```
scope :not_undo, where(undo: false)
```

very simple, and I want to do :

```
activities.not_undo.sum(:foo)
```

but an error occur:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

In fact, at the begining of my unit test, "activities" are empty. But if I do :

```
activities.where(undo: false).sum(:foo)
```

It works, even if it's empty.

So why use scope change the result? How can I do?

thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass lambda as second argument to `scope` method

```
scope :not_undo, -> { where(undo: false) }
```

Comment: ok, so why no raisl error occure when no lambda? thx for correction.